# Orchard - how to hide a widget from the home page

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

I am running Orchard version 1.7. My goal is to have an "aside second" widget displayed on all pages apart from the homepage.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
not url("~/")
```

Something like this?

Comment: To clarify, that would be the layer rule to use for this.